# How does the X-Wing's ladder retract?

Tags: star-wars, the-empire-strikes-back

Whilst watching Empire I noted that Luke climbs what appears to be a rigid ladder to get into his X-Wing when leaving Dagobah (after learning that Han, Leia, Chewie and C-3P0 may be in danger at Bespin).

Once he enters the cockpit, **how does the ladder retract?**

[image: The ladder looks too rigid to be folded??]

Comment: By the magic of handwaving.

Comment: If I designed this thing it would be a rope ladder that is just lifted into the cockpit and drops into a cubbyhole.

Comment: Regardless of what any texts/movies say, the ladder in that picture isn't even attached to the fighter.  A trch could come and haul it away.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The junior novelisation confirms that it's "retractable" (as opposed to being manually attached and then discarded).

Quite how this is *actually* accomplished isn't immediately obvious but I'd assume that it collapses into a smaller size and then slots into the body of the X-Wing somewhere near the top.

> *Yoda answered, “If you honor what they fight for … yes!”*
>
> *Luke reached for the lower rung of **the X-wing’s retractable ladder** and
> looked away from Ben and Yoda.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Empire Strikes Back - Junior Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_V:_The_Empire_Strikes_Back_(junior_novelization))</sup></sub>

---

Interestingly, a [deleted scene from Return of the Jedi](https://youtu.be/y1qyXxLIXLw?t=4m53s) has Luke climbing a similar ladder and then simply ***discarding it***. No explanation is offered for this discrepancy.

[image]

---

Pablo Hidalgo addressed this conundrum in [Star Wars Insider #60](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Insider_60), although he did stress that his answer was not part of the accepted canon.

> **Q. What's the deal with the ladder to Luke's X-wing? In a New Hope, we see his boarding ladder being removed by a tech prior to take-off. When he gets to Dagobah in Empire, a ladder mysteriously and conveniently appears so he can board, but once he's in the cockpit, it's gone. Where did it come from? Where did it go? If X-wings have some sort of automatic retractable ladders built-in, than why does the guy at the Massassi base even bother?**
>
> **PH:** It's a valid question, and there hasn't yet been a source published that's supplied a “real” answer. This response is just a stab at possible solutions and is not meant to settle any arguments. Anyway, no technical manuals point the an X-wing having a retractable ladder, so that's out. Incom representatives no doubt strongly suggest that you land your X-wing only at well-stocked facilities that provide you with a prompt and courteous ladder service.
>
> But what if you land on some forsaken planet like Dagobah? What then?
> X-wing fighters have cargo holds in their bellies that can hold 110
> kilograms of supplies - You can see it clearly in Empire. A pilot can
> access the hold by removing a section of the cockpit seat - Presumably
> that's how Luke got all those boxes and gear out of his ship when it
> was still in the Dagobah lagoon.
>
> So, that ladder is usually kept there for pilots who must put down in
> remote locations, though getting it out of the hold and draping it on
> the side of a fighter must be awkward, unless it's hinged or
> something.
>
> The odd part about Empire is that Luke never removes his ladder.
> Hopefully that was his intent, and the ladder is designed to fall off
> and litter the Dagobah countryside. Otherwise we're left with the
> unfortunate conclusion that Luke did the Star Wars equivalent of
> driving away with his coffee cup still on the roof of his car.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer there.
I never read the novel unfortunately and I appreciate the confirmation.

Many thanks again. :)

Comment: @PrimalScientist - The major issue here is that in reality, it's just fixed to the X-Wing. The retraction happens off-screen since there's no way it could happen on-screen without a pointless $50,000 special effect sequence. You might also want to reference "[liquid cable](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Monofilament_cable)" as being much the same thing.

Comment: Curiously, a deleted scene from *Return of the Jedi* shows Luke simply unhooking the ladder and tossing it away from him.

Comment: @Bob - See edit. I presume this is the scene you were talking about :-) cheers for the assist.

Comment: @Valorum That's the one.  Doesn't it seem wasteful to simply throw the ladder aside, on a planet to which he's never coming back?

Comment: @Bob - Yeah, but this assumes that you can't just pull another one out of the storage locker. Maybe it's got twenty in there all stacked up like a drinking cup dispenser

Comment: @Bob you think a universe that destroys armada's in orbit of various planets... that destroys planets... is worried about a ladder?

Comment: @Bob: Never know who might be happy to find a ladder at some later point.

Comment: @WernerCD - Littering is bad, m'kay?

Comment: I could swear there's a bit in A New Hope when they're returning from having destroyed the Death Star where the ground crew attach a ladder to Luke's X-Wing to let him get down, but I can't confirm just now... If so, seems a bit silly if it has one built in...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - They wheel it up. It's not that daft if you think about it. Better to use a fixed one (that they can keep in good condition more easily) than the collapsible one.

Comment: @Valorum: Fair enough, and if there isn't one handy, *then* he can use the built-in one.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - My car has a hand-jack in the boot but when I go to the garage, they use their own.

Comment: Many thanks all. Its certainly made me think!! A small issue but an interesting one!! :)

Comment: @Valorum Littering is bad. Laddering is even worse. (And don't get me started on lettering.)